# Setting element's language attribute causes unicode character style bugs in children

Tags: html, css, unicode

Question: Is there a proper way to set the page language such that it doesn't cause a bunch of style regressions if you use unicode characters? Or is there a simple workaround that doesn't involve scattering a bunch of `:lang` pseudo selectors throughout our css, a very inefficient solution? Other unappealing ideas I've had: stop using unicode characters and use icons instead. This would not be easy in our large and mature code-base.

Update: here is a new runnable example. It seems that only some unicode characters have this issue, and only with some fonts.

```css
body {
  font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<h3>Blackjack advice (Unicode dabblings)</h3>

<p lang="en-US">If you draw ♤, alway hit</p>
<p lang="zh-Hans">如果你画 ♤，总是打</p>

<p lang="en-US">If you draw ●, alway hit</p>
<p lang="zh-Hans">如果你画 ●，总是打</p>

<p lang="en-US">If you draw ❦, alway hit</p>
<p lang="zh-Hans">如果你画 ❦，总是打</p>


<p lang="en-US">If you draw , alway hit</p>
<p lang="zh-Hans">如果你画 ，总是打</p>

Why is ● so large in Chinese? Interestingly, changing font-family to sans-serif normalizes the size (at least in my current context, Chrome/Windows).
```

Comment: The correct answer is to not use unicode symbols for list bullets, especially if you want to address people with disabilities. Use correct markup instead and create embellishments using CSS where necessary.

Comment: why not use semantically correct tags (`ul` and `li` tags) instead of trying to make your own unordered list in a paragraph?

Comment: @Nit I would certainly do so were it easy to change. We have a complex CMS that converts text documents to html. But this question is intended to be more broadly applicable - suppose I needed to use other types of unicode symbols, for other reasons.

Comment: Hmm, this problem seems to largely go away when I use a different font-family. Perhaps that is the solution.

Comment: The actual problem which is incorrect markup is merely hidden away in that case. For example, screen reader users will still read your text as "Middle dot the differential diagnosis...". How would they know that the dot is supposed to annotate a list item? They might catch on at some point, but regardless of use it's confusing.

Comment: @Nit I agree it’s suboptimal. Ideally we would use a list item or designate the glyph as formatting using an aria attribute. Still, let’s say it was poker suit icons in an article about poker.

Comment: The problem isn't really relevant in the example you gave. Different languages handle icons differently in their alphabet and you wouldn't be trying to manually override that if you weren't using the icon for a different purpose. But I digress — there are options discussed above on how to solve this the right way, whether you have the resources to do that is up to you.

Comment: @Nit I appreciate your input. I understand that questions originating from bad design decisions are annoying. I've updated the question so that aspect is, at least, eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes):

> User agents may use the element's language to determine proper processing or rendering (e.g. in the selection of appropriate fonts or pronunciations, for dictionary selection, or for the user interfaces of form controls such as date pickers).

You asked to get you a font that's appropriate for rendering Simplified Chinese, and browser/OS did, and it just so happens that this font, at least on your system, has a differently styled `●` glyph.

I would suggest to wrap your symbols of interest in a separate tag, use it to override the font to best-fitting one (perhaps a CSS font for fine control over size/style) and also use this as a wonderful opportunity to give them alt-text/title of some kind, as personally I am already lost as to whether the circle is clubs or diamonds in your example, for the music note doesn't look like either of these suits in any of interpretations that I'm aware of.

```css
body {
  font-family: serif;
}
abbr.ico {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h3>Blackjack advice (Unicode dabblings)</h3>

<p lang="en-US">If you draw ●, alway hit</p>
<p lang="ru-RU">Если вам попался ●, ходите</p>
<p lang="zh-Hans">If you draw ●, alway hit</p>
<p lang="zh-Hans">如果你画 ●，总是打
<br>If you draw ●, alway hit</p>
<p lang="en-US">If you draw <abbr class="ico" title="a circle?">●</abbr>, alway hit</p>
<p lang="zh-Hans">如果你画 <abbr class="ico" title="a circle?">●</abbr>，总是打</p>
```